# CSS menu on hover dropdown

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make simple hover drop down menu in my header it works fine except on hover it shows additional buttons and i can't find the reason for that

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gpf5n/#&togetherjs=EleDQDiDLG

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hotel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Hotel.css">            
        <script src="HotelM.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <header>
                <div></div>
                <nav>   

                    <ul class="Menu1">
                        <li><a class="MenuButtons" href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="Menu">
                        <li><a class="MenuButtons" href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="Menu">
                        <li><a class="MenuButtons" href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="Menu">
                        <li><a class="MenuButtons" href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="Menu">
                        <li><a class="MenuButtons" href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body , div ,h1, h2, section,canvas, main, footer , header , p , a, article, ul ,li, ol, table {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
} 
main{
    width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;

    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#2ab0ed+0,9fd8ef+27,9fd8ef+27,bfe8f9+52,9fd8ef+79,2ab0ed+100 */
background: rgb(42,176,237); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(42,176,237,1) 0%, rgba(159,216,239,1) 27%, rgba(159,216,239,1) 27%, rgba(191,232,249,1) 52%, rgba(159,216,239,1) 79%, rgba(42,176,237,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(42,176,237,1) 0%,rgba(159,216,239,1) 27%,rgba(159,216,239,1) 27%,rgba(191,232,249,1) 52%,rgba(159,216,239,1) 79%,rgba(42,176,237,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(42,176,237,1) 0%,rgba(159,216,239,1) 27%,rgba(159,216,239,1) 27%,rgba(191,232,249,1) 52%,rgba(159,216,239,1) 79%,rgba(42,176,237,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2ab0ed', endColorstr='#2ab0ed',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */

}
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #7142AA;
}
header div{
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;    
}
header nav{
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;    
    padding-left: 0.5%;
}
header nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%; 
    height: 100%;
}
nav li{
    height: 100%;
}
nav a{
    font-size: 1.7em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #6025A8;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center; 
    display: none;
}
.MenuButtons{
    font-size: 1.7em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #6025A8;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block; 
}
.Menu1:hover a{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I clicked through to your fiddle and became immediately uncomfortable with the extra nav and floating icons all over my screen.

Comment: hmm dunno paste it to your fiddle, Im new in Jsfiddle

Comment: @Jay use this http://jsfiddle.net/gpf5n/

Comment: "shows additional buttons" You mean action 1 and 2 ? Or the bullets ?

Comment: i mean it should display block 4 addition butons instead it shows them but it shows additonal linear buttons which are not even in the "ul"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gpf5n/ On here I see only 1 item with 2 sub items

Comment: Or you want "action 1/2 " to be on the same line as Take action ?

Comment: seems like i havent given you the proper Jsfiddle link 
can you guys copy paste the HTML and CSS and create your own Jsfiddle and see what my problem is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94925/discussion-between-velko-georgiev-and-georgi-antonov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the ul floating elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/b4wkhqLb/

```css
body , div ,h1, h2, section,canvas, main, footer , header , p , a, article, ul ,li, ol, table {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
} 
main{
    width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;

    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#2ab0ed+0,9fd8ef+27,9fd8ef+27,bfe8f9+52,9fd8ef+79,2ab0ed+100 */
background: rgb(42,176,237); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(42,176,237,1) 0%, rgba(159,216,239,1) 27%, rgba(159,216,239,1) 27%, rgba(191,232,249,1) 52%, rgba(159,216,239,1) 79%, rgba(42,176,237,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(42,176,237,1) 0%,rgba(159,216,239,1) 27%,rgba(159,216,239,1) 27%,rgba(191,232,249,1) 52%,rgba(159,216,239,1) 79%,rgba(42,176,237,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(42,176,237,1) 0%,rgba(159,216,239,1) 27%,rgba(159,216,239,1) 27%,rgba(191,232,249,1) 52%,rgba(159,216,239,1) 79%,rgba(42,176,237,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2ab0ed', endColorstr='#2ab0ed',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */

}
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #7142AA;
}
header div{
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;    
}
header nav{
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;    
    padding-left: 0.5%;
}
header nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%; 
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
nav li{
    height: 100%;
}
nav a{
    font-size: 1.7em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #6025A8;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center; 
    display: none;
}
.MenuButtons{
    font-size: 1.7em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #6025A8;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
.Menu1:hover a{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
        <main>
            <header>
                <div></div>
                <nav>   

                    <ul class="Menu1">
                        <li><a class="MenuButtons" href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="Menu">
                        <li><a class="MenuButtons" href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="Menu">
                        <li><a class="MenuButtons" href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="Menu">
                        <li><a class="MenuButtons" href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="Menu">
                        <li><a class="MenuButtons" href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </main>
```

Comment: Thanks! but what was the purpose of it why additonal elements were shown

Comment: Those weren't additional element.. They were the rest on the main menus.
When you put the mouse over the menu and the sub menus were displayed  the main div was expanded . So all child div went to the bottom

Comment: but the rest of the main menus are more than 4 and my code was showing additioanl 4

Comment: You have 5 menus. When you hover 1 the sub menus were expanding the parent element, showing the 4 sub menus, and sending the 4 main menus to the bottom. so it total you had 1 main menu at the top 4 verticals and 4 at the bottom ( at the bottom 4 mains + 1 vertical )

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a lot off extra HTML Markup

**CSS**

```
nav ul {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: 40px;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
nav ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    background:#7142AA;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
body, div, h1, h2, section, canvas, main, footer, header, p, a, article, ul, li, ol, table {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
    width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#2ab0ed+0,9fd8ef+27,9fd8ef+27,bfe8f9+52,9fd8ef+79,2ab0ed+100 */
    background: rgb(42, 176, 237);
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(42, 176, 237, 1) 0%, rgba(159, 216, 239, 1) 27%, rgba(159, 216, 239, 1) 27%, rgba(191, 232, 249, 1) 52%, rgba(159, 216, 239, 1) 79%, rgba(42, 176, 237, 1) 100%);
    /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(42, 176, 237, 1) 0%, rgba(159, 216, 239, 1) 27%, rgba(159, 216, 239, 1) 27%, rgba(191, 232, 249, 1) 52%, rgba(159, 216, 239, 1) 79%, rgba(42, 176, 237, 1) 100%);
    /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(42, 176, 237, 1) 0%, rgba(159, 216, 239, 1) 27%, rgba(159, 216, 239, 1) 27%, rgba(191, 232, 249, 1) 52%, rgba(159, 216, 239, 1) 79%, rgba(42, 176, 237, 1) 100%);
    /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#2ab0ed', endColorstr='#2ab0ed', GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #7142AA;
}
header div {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
header nav {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0.5%;
}
header nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav a {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<main>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="Menu1">
                <li><a href="#">ASD1</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">2</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">3</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="MenuButtons" href="#">ASD</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="MenuButtons" href="#">ASD</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">ASD</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="MenuButtons" href="#">ASD</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">ASD</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="MenuButtons" href="#">ASD</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASD</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</main>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/gpf5n/256/)**